# RSpec2 model class collision with Capybara class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, rspec2

I have a model class named "Driver" in my project. After trying to do some tests, Rspec threw this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `create!' for Capybara::Driver:Module
```

So I think there's a problem in the way RSpec detects the classes or something. Here's the spec (simplified obviously):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Driver do
    it "works! a driver can be created!" do
      Driver.create!
    end
end
```

I'm using

```
rspec-* (2.0.0)
capybara (0.4.0)
rails (3.0.0)
```

Anyone faced something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this instead and remove the collision:

```
describe "::Driver" do
end
```

Comment: almost :( It didin't work BUT! now I can use the Driver class inside my DriversController spec just using ::Driver instead of Driver. Is really annoying but at least works.

Comment: Ok, it works using: describe '::Driver' do.. Please edit the answer so other can use that. Thank you!